# Are we able to modify the chatter digest content?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-chatter

I want the customize format for chatter digest mail. So, Are we able to modify the content of chatter daily digest sent through the mail? or is there any way to achieve this requirement?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's any way to change the content of the digest emails.